# Simultaneous outgoing call to user using twilio in iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, phone-call

I'ld like to make native call to user until user answer the call (Recursive call). If in case of voice mail than also doing same. Is it possible using `Twilio` in my iOS application.

Also i want to know whether call is answered by human or machine.

If yes than please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this by leveraging [`StatusCallBack`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter), Something like this:

```
    $sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
    $token = "your_auth_token"; 
    $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$call = $client->account->calls->create("+18668675309", "+14155551212", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", array(
    "Method" => "GET",
    "IfMachine"=>"Hangup",
    "StatusCallback" => "https://www.myapp.com/check_call_status.php",
    "StatusCallbackMethod" => "POST"
    ));
```

> **StatusCallBack:** A URL that Twilio will send asynchronous webhook
>   requests to on every call event specified in the StatusCallbackEvent
>   parameter. If no event is present, Twilio will send completed by
>   default. If an ApplicationSid parameter is present, this parameter is
>   ignored. URLs must contain a valid hostname (underscores are not
>   permitted).

So in your StatusCallBack URL (https://www.myapp.com/check_call_status.php) you would have some logic to determine if the call was answered, and if it was answered by a human not an answering machine. Your StatusCallBack endpoint would look something like this:

```
<?php 

if($_REQUEST['CallStatus'] == 'no-asnwer' || $_REQUEST['AnsweredBy'] == 'machine'){
        // call again!
        $sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
        $token = "your_auth_token"; 
        $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

    $call = $client->account->calls->create("+18668675309", "+14155551212", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", array(
        "Method" => "GET",
        "IfMachine"=>"Hangup",
        "StatusCallback" => "https://www.myapp.com/check_call_status.php",
        "StatusCallbackMethod" => "POST"
        ));
}
```